# Vim: how to use Ex commands across files (global marks?)

Tags: vim

I wanted to know if I can move/copy some lines from one file to another in vim by using Ex commands and global marks.

I can do so on the current file by setting the destination mark at the cursor position (ma), going to the source, selecting some lines and then issue the command:

```
:'<,'>m 'a
```

And the selected lines are moved to destination. But how to do so across files? I tried using global marks to move to another file:

```
:'<,'>m 'A
```

But the error "E20: Mark not set" is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not possible. From the help on `mark`:

> Uppercase marks 'A to 'Z include the file name.  {Vi: no uppercase marks}
>   You can use them to jump from file to file.  **You can only use an uppercase
>   mark with an operator if the mark is in the current file.**

They are really just supposed to let you jump. Also important, from help on
`{address}`:

> <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> = position of mark T (uppercase); **when the mark is in another
>   file it cannot be used in a range**